# Bash, finding functions whose contents match a search string

Tags: bash, text-processing

I want to search all defined functions in bash for some search string. The below is a start, but I want to then eliminate all terms that are *not* followed by whitespace on the next line (i.e. eliminate all entries that did not find `$1` in the body of that function).

```
fu() { declare -f | grep -e \(\) -e $1; }
```

e.g. This output:

```
...
tt ()
untargz ()
urlfix ()
ver ()
    [ -f /etc/lsb-release ] && RELEASE="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCRIPTION | sed 's/^.*=//g' | sed 's/\"//g') ";
vi. ()
vi.su ()
...
```

would reduce to

```
...
ver ()
    [ -f /etc/lsb-release ] && RELEASE="$(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCRIPTION | sed 's/^.*=//g' | sed 's/\"//g') ";
...
```

An even much much better way (if possible) would be if every matching function could be determined and displayed in full.

I envision that roughly as:

- Collect the names of the functions with the search string in their body (the name of the function is always a single word on a line before the match, starting at `^` followed by a space then the line ending with `()$`), then using `command -V` on each of those names, OR, doing a `declare -f` again but this time, using those names and matching everything after them from `{` to `}` (where `{` and `}` are on single lines by themselves at `^` - I know that grep/awk/sed can do amazing things to those that have such knowledge.

End result would be running `fu awk` and it will show me the definition of every function that contains `awk` in the body of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `awk` command on the receiving end of the pipe comes to mind:

```
declare -f | awk -v srch="pattern" 'NF==2 && $2=="()"{if (m) print buf; buf=""; m=0}
                                    buf && index($0,srch){m=1}
                                    {buf=buf ORS $0}
                                    END{if (m) print buf}'
```

The idea is to store the declaration and body of each function in a buffer `buf` while parsing the output of `declare -f`, but only print the buffer if the search string was found.

- The program will recognize the start of a new function definition if it encounters a line consisting of only two fields (= space-separated "words"), where the second field is `()`. If a match was found while parsing the previous function (indicated by the flag `m` being 1), the buffer `buf` will be printed. Both the buffer and the flag will be reset.
- The search word is passed to the program as `awk` variable `srch`. If it is found on the current line (the `index` function returns a non-zero result), the `m` flag is set to 1, but only if we are not on the line where the function declaration starts (indicated by `buf` not being empty), otherwise matches in the function *name* would also count.
- Every line will be appended to the buffer `buf`, and separated from the previous content by the output record separator `ORS` (which defaults to newline).
- At the end, another check is performed if the match was found, and if so, the buffer printed. Without that check the last function definition would never be considered.

**Note**

The program performs a full-string search by using the `index()` function of `awk`. If you want the search to be based on regular expression matching, you would need to change the condition from

```
index($0,srch)
```

to

```
$0~srch
```

(but, as always, be aware that searching for strings that contain characters which have special meanings for regular expressions becomes more cumbersome).

Comment: Incredible, and thanks for the detailed explanation, `awk` is something that I find difficult, so it's great to learn this . My final function works a treat (it does use a 3rd party tool, but that's just something that I find a bit better than `pymentize` for visually scanning scripts). `fu() { declare -f | awk -v srch="$1" 'NF==2 && $2=="()"{if (m) print buf; buf=""; m=0} index($0,srch){m=1} {buf=buf ORS $0} END{if (m) print buf}' | bat -pp -f -l bash; }`

Answer (score 4):

For those looking at doing the same thing in `zsh`, to get the function definitions of functions whose body matches a pattern, you'd do:

```
typeset -f '<dummy>' ${(k)functions[(R)pattern]}
```

the `<dummy>` to cover for the case where there's no matching function. Or a cleaner way:

```
() { (($#)) && typeset -f -- "$@"; } ${(k)functions[(R)pattern]}
```

In `bash`, you could do something similar with:

```
compgen -A function | (
  ret=1
  while IFS= read -r fn; do
    def=$(typeset -f -- "$fn") &&
      [[ ${def#*'()'} = pattern ]] &&
      printf '%s\n' "$def" &&
      ret=0
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

Though that's quite inefficient as the list of function names is read one byte at a time (as `read`'s input is a pipe), and one process is forked for each function. It could be optimised with:

```
compgen -A function | (
  readarray -t functions
  for fn in "${functions[@]}"; do
    typeset -f -- "$fn" && printf '\0'
  done
) | (
  ret=1
  readarray -td '' fn_definitions
  for def in "${fn_definitions[@]}"; do
    [[ ${def#*'()'} = pattern ]] &&
      printf '%s\n' "$def" &&
      ret=0
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

`readarray`, contrary to `read`, doesn't need to read the input one byte at a time as it consumes all the input anyway. We delimit the function definitions with NUL characters as anyway `bash` (contrary to `zsh`) can't store that character in its function definitions/names nor variables contents and then we can use `readarray -td ''` (which requires bash-4.4+) to break that into an array.

That avoids having to rely on heuristics such as the presence of `()` (which could very well also occur in the body of a function) to guess where each function definition starts in the output of `typeset -f`.